# Python Iterate in a list, detect repetions and concatenate to the repetion a number

Tags: python, list, count, repeat

```
colours=[red,green,blue,yellow,red,red,black,blue,yellow]
```

I want to update this list so the result should be something like:

```
colours=[red1,green,blue1,yellow1,red2,red3,black,blue2,yellow2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a counter to identify repeated colours, and build a dict of colour name to an `itertools.count(1)` object. Then use a list-comp to append the next number to a colour where that colour has been repeated, eg:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import count

colours=['red','green','blue','yellow','red','red','black','blue','yellow']
repeated = {k:count(1) for k, v in Counter(colours).items() if v > 1}
new_colours = [colour + str(next(repeated[colour])) if colour in repeated else colour for colour in colours]
# ['red1', 'green', 'blue1', 'yellow1', 'red2', 'red3', 'black', 'blue2', 'yellow2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def append_counts(colours):
  tally = {}
  result = []
  colours.reverse()
  while colours:
    colour = colours.pop()
    tally[colour] = tally.get(colour, 0) + 1
    result.append("%s%d" % (colour, tally[colour]))
  return result

append_counts(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow'])
```

Note: This mutates the colours argument, be careful.

Edit: Another approach that does not mutate the colours argument:

```
def append_counts(colours):
  def reducer((counts, hist), colour):
    hist[colour] = hist.get(colour, 0) + 1
    counts.append("%s%d" % (colour, hist[colour]))
    return counts, hist
  return reduce(reducer, colours, ([], {}))[0]

append_counts(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow'])
```

Comment: It's close - although the order is now reversed (perhaps `.pop(0)`?) and from the OPs example output - unique colours should not have any numbers appended

Comment: No, not pop(0), it is slow. Rather colours.reverse() before a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be deranged

```
[colors[x] + str(len([c for c in colors[:x+1] if c == colors[x]]) if colors[x] in colors[:x] + colors[x+1:] else '') for x in range(len(colors))]
```

Comment: I simply love deranged!

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
This is perhaps not as fast as I would like, but it works according to all specifications.
+ 1. Updates the list (changes the given list instead of constructing a new one)
+ 2. Unique items aren't marked with numbers
"""

def append_counts (colours):
    tally = {}
    get = tally.get
    for x in colours:
        v = get(x, 0)
        tally[x] = v+1+(v==1)
    for x in xrange(len(colours)-1, -1, -1):
        c = colours[x]
        tally[c] -= 1
        colours[x] = ("%s%d" % (c, tally[c]), c)[tally[c]==0]

>>> # Example:
>>> colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow']
>>> append_counts(colours)
>>> colours
['red1', 'green', 'blue1', 'yellow1', 'red2', 'red3', 'black', 'blue2', 'yellow2']
```